# Null cannot be for 'stream'

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook

I keep getting an exception everytime i try to display an image in an emailbody of the project im currently doing. It is retrieving image in a sharepoint picture library to be displayed as an attachment. This is my code and i am having errors on line 264 which is currently calling the method.

```
  if (txtEventPictureURL.Text != "")
         {
            string siteurl = "http://it3127:30091";
             string filename = txtEventPictureURL.Text;

             System.Drawing.Image imgForCallOut = Image.FromStream(GetImageforCharts(siteurl, filename));   //LINE 264 ERROR

             mailItem.HTMLBody = Environment.NewLine + @"<html>Event Title : " + txtTitle.Text +
            Environment.NewLine + "Event Description : " + txtDescription.Text + Environment.NewLine + "
            Event Start Date From :" + dtpStartDate.Text + " To " + dtpEndDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Time From : " + cbStartHours.Text + " : " +
            cbStartMins.Text + " To " + cbEndHours.Text + " : " + cbEndMins.Text + "Image : " + "<img src=" + imgForCallOut + " /> </html>"; 

             //var doc = global.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow().WordEditor;
             //var pic = doc.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("MY IMAGE URL", true);
             //doc.Application.Selection.Hyperlinks.add(pic, "MY URL");

         }  



  }

    public static MemoryStream GetImageforCharts(string siteUrl, string fileName)
    {
        Byte[] fileContentsArray = null;
        MemoryStream imageStream = null;

        //siteUrl = "http://it3127:30091/";
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            // using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPPictureLibrary chartPictureLibrary = (SPPictureLibrary)web.Lists["Pictures"];
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name ='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + fileName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                    SPListItemCollection lstImages = chartPictureLibrary.GetItems(query);
                    foreach (SPListItem r in lstImages)
                    {
                        SPFile file = r.File;
                        using (Stream fileContents = file.OpenBinaryStream())
                        {
                            long length = fileContents.Length;
                            fileContentsArray = new Byte[length];
                            fileContents.Read(fileContentsArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(length));
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

          imageStream = new MemoryStream(fileContentsArray);
            return imageStream;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message that you get? and where in your code does the error occur?

Comment: @roqz hi. I get an unhandled exception messagebox that state "Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream' " .. And i have comment on line 264 that that is where the error occured at. But if you don't see it, it's here ; 

System.Drawing.Image imgForCallOut = Image.FromStream(GetImageforCharts(siteurl, filename));

Comment: You are getting exception in `GetImageforCharts` but you are catching it and handling by returning null which as you see is very bad in your case, put a breakpoint there and see what real exception you get.

Comment: @gzaxx im sorry but somehow i cant run on debugging mode for this project. Maybe it's because it is an add-in project?

Comment: then remove `try ... catch` block from second method and lets see what you get then.

Comment: @gzaxx okay. so basically, i removed and this is what i get. it3127:30091 is my site name. Did i instantiate wrongly or something ?

The web application at http://it3127:30091 could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL corerctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

Comment: This stackoverflow didn't let me type http or something inside?

Comment: the url is correct? do you have the neccessary rights?

Answer (score 0):

As gzaxx said, you are ignoring an exception inside `GetImageforCharts()` and then returning `null`.

In this case, `GetImageforCharts()` wouldn't know what to do when an exception occurs - the calling code requires it to send an object of type `MemoryStream` and when creating that fails, all you could do is return `null`.

But instead of catching the exception there, you could remove the exception handler from `GetImageforCharts()` and catch it in the calling code. Alternatively you could keep the exception handler, optionally log the message, and

```
throw new ApplicationException("Error getting image for charts", ex);
```

so you have more control over which exception you have to catch when calling the method.

A third option is create a method

```
bool TryGetImageforCharts(...params..., out MemoryStream stream)
```

which returns `false` if the image could not be found (like the `int.TryParse()` method).

Comment: well , that might handles for the exception part. but do you know how to solve the problem i got on the site?

Comment: You solve the "Null problem" by not returning `null`. Currently you are receiving an exception and ignoring it. The exception message contains a clue for that. Since we don't know _anything_ about the exception, it could even be an `OutOfMemoryException`.